# Ionic 3 cordova media play on button click not working on android but working in web view

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have implemented the code to play an audio when button is clicked. working perfectly when i run command ionic serve and it opens in browser but when i build .apk and test it on android it does not play audio when button clicked. attaching my html and typescript controller code.

### html

```
<ion-col class = "mystyle"  (click)="wajid()"  >
   <ion-label id = "aa"   > اَبَدًا </ion-label>   </ion-col>
<ion-col>
```

### controller

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    }


    wajid()
    {
        document.getElementById("aa").style.color = "blue";
        var bleep = new Audio();
        bleep.src = '../assets/sounds/q1p14_1.mp3';
        bleep.play();
        bleep.onended = function() {
            document.getElementById("aa").style.color = "red";
        }
    }
}
```

kindly help me to play audio on android phone. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change asset url to below

```
bleep.src = './assets/sounds/q1p14_1.mp3';
```

Why? Here is the explanation...

When we make build everything goes inside `www` folder, Inside there is `index.html` and `assets` folder that's why because of index.html and assets folder in the same level.

Comment: i changed the path as you said still not working on android phone but working in web view (ionic serve)

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
  
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }


  wajid()
  {
  document.getElementById("aa").style.color = "blue";
  var bleep = new Audio();
  bleep.src = './assets/sounds/q1p14_1.mp3';
  bleep.play();
  bleep.onended = function() {
  document.getElementById("aa").style.color = "red";
  }
  }
}

Comment: that is looks correct. Can you please check console any error there?

Comment: no error on console dear when i click on button in web view it plays audio perfectly even on every device (ionic lab) but when i run it on android phone its text color changed but audio doen`st play :(

Comment: Please send me your apk

Comment: where to send apk ?

Comment: Upload somewhere and give me a link here

Comment: did you get .apk ?

Comment: That is working man. Please verify checked in your apk again.

Comment: I am able to listen something like ali

Comment: did you checked in your android physical device or on emulator ?